# Puppeteer. Page.evluate() is not running or not getting results

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to run very simple example of Pupeteer. But in page.evalute() method just nothing happening, no errors, no result. What I'm doing wrong?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
    module.exports = class zrGrabber {
        async startGrabbing() {
            try {
                const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
                const page = await browser.newPage();
                await page.goto('https://www.zr.ru/news/avtomobili/');
                await page.evaluate(() => {
                    const links = document.querySelectorAll(`div.head > h2 > a`)
                    console.log(links)
                });
                browser.close();
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
    }
```

and that's how it's running on Node:

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;
const cron = require('node-cron');
const zrGrabber = require('./grabbers/zr.grabber');

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    response.end('Hello Node.js Server!')
}
const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)
server.listen(port, (err) => {
    cron.schedule('* * * * *', async () => {
        const zr = new zrGrabber();
        await zr.startGrabbing();
    });
    if (err) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', err)
    }
    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(links)` is executed in the page context, so `links` is outputted in the browser console (you can see it if you launch the Chrome in the visible mode and open DevTools before closing the browser). If you need this to be outputted in the Node.js process console, you need to return serializable value, get it and manage it in the Node.js context:

```js
                const links = await page.evaluate(() => {
                    const links = document.querySelectorAll(`div.head > h2 > a`);
                    return [...links].map(link => link.href);
                });
                console.log(links);
                browser.close();
```